# Database relationship 1:1 vs 1:0..1

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm trying to learn these relationships. Is it correct as I show below that:

**1)** I will have a **1:0..1** relation by simply making the identity key of the parent also the identity key of the child?

**2)** To make it **1:1**, I add an FK in parent table, connecting the two Identity columns?

Is this all there is to it? And please correct me if my wording is not exact/correct.

```
1:0..1
```

**Customer**(Id {PK, Identity}, Name)

**CustomerAddress**(CustomerId {PK, FK, Identity}, StreetName)

**FK_CustomerAddress_Customer**(CustomerId, Id)

```
1:1
```

**Customer**(Id {PK, FK, Identity}, Name)

**FK_Customer_CustomerAddress**(Id, CustomerId)

**CustomerAddress**(CustomerId {PK, FK, Identity}, Streetname)

**FK_CustomerAddress_Costumer**(CustomerId, Id)

---

**EDIT1:**

I believe both above was wrong, and solution is like this: (?)

```
1:0..1
```

**Customer**(Id *{PK, Identity}*, Name)

**CustomerAddress**(CustomerId *{PK, FK, UNIQUE}*, StreetName)

**FK_CustomerAddress_Customer**(CustomerId, Id)

Comment: I'm wondering if you mean `1:0..1` ("one to zero or one").

Comment: Yes, I meant that, will edit.

Comment: Please fix your spelling of your tables and fields if you mean customer not costumer (which is a person who designs costumes). ANd ID is a terrible choice for the identity field. It will cause issues with reporting (reports don't like multiple columns with the same names) and is very easy to make mistakes in joins. Use tablenameId instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A 1:1 relationship between two tables means that each tuple in each table maps to exactly one tuple in the other. This is more formally known as a Bijection. It's a limitation of SQL that for most practical purposes bijection is effectively impossible to achieve in a SQL database. That's because SQL requires each table to be updated individually and therefore there is no way to update two such tables unless you temporarily disable one of the constraints.

A 1:0/1 relationship is also known as an Surjection (your first example). Surjection is the standard behaviour of a SQL-style "FOREIGN KEY" constraint assuming nulls are not permitted. The constraint is always optional on one side of the relationship.

NOTE: The IDENTITY property isn't relevant to your example. It's the key and foreign key constraints that define the relationship.

Comment: A DBMS that supports deferrable constraints can enforce a 1:1 relationship using only DDL. You might be able to get the same effect on SQL Server with triggers if it's essential, but I'm too tired to think that hard right now.

Comment: Yes you can do it with a deferrable constraint. However, a deferrable constraint is just a constraint that can be temporarily disabled so that the constraint can be violated each time you do an update. In other words the constraint isn't really being enforced as a declarative constraint at all. SQL's support for multi-table constraints is extremely limited in this respect. The workaround in SQL Server would be to disable the constraint and then re-enable it.

Comment: @dportas: "a deferrable constraint is just a constraint that can be temporarily disabled so that the constraint can be violated each time you do an update". That's one way to look at it. Another way is to say a deferrable constraint is a constraint that's checked at the end of an arbitrary series of SQL statements (at the end of a transaction0 rather than somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Thanks! I think I mix up "unique" and "identity". What is really an identity column? What can it do or be used to that a Unique column can not?   I also got a problem when making these tables in Management Studio. (1:0) I can add a Customer, but not able to add a row to CustomerAddress... (?)

Comment: Oh.. I had to remove Identity on CustomerAddressID of course, then I could insert.  ..Plz see EDIT1 above.. Will this be correct then?

Comment: bretddog, IDENTITY is just a feature that generates a new number for each row inserted. An IDENTITY column doesn't have to have unique values and a column that is unique doesn't have to be an IDENTITY.

Comment: Yea, silly of me.. Hmmm.. I get your last point.. But "an identity column doesn't have to have unique values"?  This puzzles me. I thought i.e. an autogenerated integer would always be unique. How can it otherwise "idenfity" anything? But you say I must set a Unique index on the ID field too?

Comment: IDENTITY is not in itself a uniqueness constraint. If you want to be certain an IDENTITY column is unique you should add a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint to it - otherwise it is perfectly possible to insert duplicate values. The name is perhaps not a good one. AUTOINCREMENT would be a more accurate name but IDENTITY is what standard SQL calls it.

Answer (score 4):

A foreign key can only point one way; if you make it point two ways, you could never insert a row, since an insert can only operate on one table a time.

So the solution you list for 1:0,1 is typically used for both cases.  As far as I know, SQL Server offers no way to enfore the second 1 in a 1:1 constraint.

Comment: Cheers! It's starting to make sense :)

Comment: bretdog... don't forget to accept an answer.  Otherwise you end up with a bad reputation and you'll stop getting answers altogether :P

Comment: Oracle and PostgreSQL support the *standard* feature of "Deferrable constraints". You can effectively have a 1:1 relationship.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting read on the subject:

[ON POFN* AND POOD* - TWO COMPLEMENTARY DATABASE DESIGN PRINCIPLES with Fabian Pascal, Hugh Darwen and David McGoveran](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/3010532.htm)

> I always teach the loss of this
>   constraint [circular FKs] as another
>   advantage of normalisation, not a
>   problem with it!

Comment: What do you mean by "advantage of normalisation"? That a 1:1 should not be used in the first place?

Comment: @bretddog: those aren't my words but Hugh Darwen's. Follow the link (http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/3010532.htm) and read the article! :)

Comment: Ok. I still don't understand it. A bit above my level. Since you use the quote, you should be able to explain.. ;)

Comment: @bretddog: "you should be able to explain.. ;)" -- I'll try :) The disadvantage of having a circular FK is that you would suffer update anomalies of the kind normalization prevents e.g. deleting an address would cause the customer to be deleted, cannot enter a customer into the database until their address is known, etc. FWIW it seems to me that `Address` is an attribute of a `Customer`, rather than it being a 1:1 relationship between two entities.

Comment: I see. Good to be aware of that about deleting etc, I haven't tried that yet.. These tables were just for example. I have a table with about 100 columns, where they are logically of 3 different categories. So that's why it feels more manageable to split it in 3 tables with two having a 1:1 with the first. I believe I will also map these "categories" to 1:1 parent:child domain objects, so perhaps(?) it also makes repository easier to write up.