# sql integrity 1-1 or 1-0

Tags: sql

I have a question on an exam that i don't know how to solve.

this is the question:

How do you keep the integrity of a 1-1 or 1-0 relationship between 2 tables?

Now a primary key and foreign key wouldn't work because then you can have a 1-m relationship. Maybe you can use unique in some way or alternative key?

We need to give the create table expressions and explain why this would work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database relationship 1:1 vs 1:0..1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748150/database-relationship-11-vs-10-1)

Comment: What do you mean by "1-0" relationship? 1-1 can be done in Oracle and PostgreSQL.

Comment: i looked at that post, doesn't seem to be marked as solved. I also think it is unclear what is the answer in that post.

Comment: The "1-m" relationship you mention can be reduced to a "1-1" by adding a unique constraint in the foreign table. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to give example from oracle

Here is 1:1 relationship example

```
create table state
(
    sid number(3) ,
    name varchar2(100),
    gid number(3) not null,
    constraint state_pk primary key (sid),
    constraint gov_state_fk foreign key (gid) references gov(gid)
);
```

Here is 1:0..1 relationship (a.k.a. Surjection)

```
create table state
(
    sid number(3) ,
    name varchar2(100),
    gid number(3) ,
    constraint state_pk primary key (sid),
    constraint gov_state_fk foreign key (gid) references gov(gid)
);
```

basicly what differs is,

- In 1:0 relationship gid can be nullable
- In 1:0..1 relationship gid cannot be null

**EDIT**: I also added Unicity for preserving 1:0..1 and 1:1 relationship.

Comment: what does the gov table look like? same setup as the state table?

Comment: I think the 1:1 example may be wrong. Those constraints would allow a row in `gov` to be related to no row in `state`.

Comment: @Simonare Not to be pedantic or anything, but I still think the `gov` table (not shown) needs to have a constraint to ensure the 1:1 relationship.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a 1-1 relationship in PostgreSQL. It requires the *standard* SQL feature of deferrable constraints:

```
create table employee (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(20),
  desk_id int not null,

  constraint uq1 unique (desk_id),
  constraint fk1 foreign key (desk_id) references desk (id)
    deferrable initially immediate
);

create table desk (
  id int primary key not null,
  desk_code varchar(20).
  employee_id int not null,

  constraint uq2 unique (employee_id),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (employee_id) references employee (id)
    deferrable initially immediate
);
```

In simple English: every row of `employee` points to a `desk`. Every `desk` points to an `employee`.

Deferrable constraints are only implemented in PostgreSQL and Oracle, as far as I know.